# libxml2 use for ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, libxml2, xcode4

When I use libxml2 in my ipad project (i use the dylib and add the header flags correctly) it doesn't build and gives the error:

/Xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h:24

Expected '=','','.','asm' or '**atrribute**' before 'void'.

line 23-25 of xmlversion.h is

```
#ifndef LIBXML2_COMPILING_MSCCDEF
XMLPUBFUN void XMLCALL xmlCheckVersion(int version);
#endif /* LIBXML2_COMPILING_MSCCDEF */
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance!
Kristof

Comment: is there  a # sign before the ifndef?

Comment: yes, it was a formatting issue :)

Comment: Assuming you have correctly added the library and the path for its headers, the problem may be related to the compiler you are using. What compiler are you using? Try compiling your project with a different compiler: if you are using gcc, try using llvm or llvm-gcc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I dug up an older project that compiles directly against libxml2.

Do you have "/usr/include/libxml2" in your `Header Search Paths` project build setting?

Comment: It was a problem in the wrapper library using libxml.

Comment: @Kristof, Can you expand on your answer and perhaps post. I am having the same issue after someone has edited code in the project and I am unable to find the cause. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue. @Kristof can you elaborate your answer ?